# How do i make stackdriver graphs show 24 hour format dates

Tags: monitoring, google-stackdriver

In my stackdriver dashboard, the horizontal axis is always date/time but it displays in am/pm format, e.g. 5pm, which is a pain as everything else in my workflow is 24hour.

[image]

I cannot for the life of me find anything in my Stackdriver profile to control date/time formatting, and my GCP account is already set to 24 hour format

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The 24h format is not implemented in Stackdriver Monitoring yet.

I recommend you to open a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) explaining your needs, and the proper team will evaluate its implementation.

Hope this information helps!

Regards,

Comment: thanks, request made https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139217601